# Wifi Driver not Detected in Xubuntu 16.04 for Dell Inspiron 15R 5521?

Tags: wireless-networking

My wifi was working fine until yesterday but today it just won't work. I have included the wireless-info.txt at https://paste.ubuntu.com/23711855/.

It seems `iwlwifi` is causing issues.

Edit:- As Suggested, I reset the BIOS settings and it seemed to work for a few hours. Then later the problem returned.

Comment: Try checking that wifi isn't disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I reset the BIOS settings and wifi seemed to work but I am again facing the  same issue.

Comment: If the wireless adapter showed up after resetting the BIOS and then vanished again this is very likely a hardware and or firmware issue unrelated to Ubuntu. It's not that Ubuntu doesn't know what to do with the wireless chipset; it's that Ubuntu isn't even aware of its existence according to your network diagnostics – which can only mean the computer firmware doesn't announce its presence for some reason. You should request for your question to be migrated to [SU] by a moderate via the "flag" link below it. On [SU] such problems are on topic.